# Node.js: Pass variables to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am sending a .`XML` file using `res.sendfile 'xml/foo.xml'`. How can I pass variables to the `foo.xml` file and change the .XML content accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `res.sendfile 'xml/foo.xml'`, you'll have to use a template file and pass your variables into a library that will parse the template and give you the XML for each request. While there are many templating engines for Node.js, the two that Express supports by default are [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) and [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/). Jade is Haml-like, which is cool, but if you're working with existing XML, then you should probably stick to EJS. EJS lets you just take ordinary HTML or XML and embed JavaScript in it.

So, you'd rename `xml/foo.xml` to `views/foo.ejs` and, instead of `res.sendfile`, you'd write something like

```
res.contentType 'text/xml'
res.render 'foo.ejs', obj
```

where `obj` contains all of the variables that you want to make available to the template.

Check the [Express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) on "View Rendering" for more information.